# why im getting this error: undefined is not an object evaluating this.state.tracks[0].id REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

im building a music player, so when the app runs, it will get all music files with this function:

```
 requestPermission = async () => {

    try {

        const permission = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(
            [
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            ],
        );

        if (permission["android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"] === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED && permission["android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"] === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            try {
                let tracks = [];
                let tracks_object = []; 
                tracks = await MusicFiles.getAll({
                    cover: true,
                });
                let length = tracks.length;
                for (i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
                    tracks_object.push(new Tracks_info(tracks.results[i]));
                }
                this.setState({tracks: tracks_object}, () => this.init_player());
            }catch(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        }else {
            this.requestPermission();
        }
    
    }catch (error) {
        alert(error)
    }
};
```

as you can see once i setted the tracks, i run the function `init_player`

```
 init_player = async () => {
    try {
        if (this.random_tracks) {
            let tracks = this.random_queue();
            await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
            await TrackPlayer.add(tracks);
            this.setState({random_tracks: tracks, last_id_song: tracks[tracks.length - 1].id});
        }else {
            let tracks = this.state.tracks;
            await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
            await TrackPlayer.add(tracks);
            this.setState({first_id_song: tracks[0].id, last_id_song: tracks[this.state.tracks.length - 1].id})
        }
    }catch(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

but in the render when I tried to print the first position of the array with the tracks it doesnt let me:

`<Text style = {{color: "white"}}>{this.state.tracks[0].title}</Text>`

giving the error: `error: undefined is not an object evaluating this.state.tracks[0].id` with any property, but when it lets me prints the length, `this.state.tracks.length`, that means that the state is already set, but why doesnt let me print the property?

Answer (score -1):

Initialize state first like

```
state = { tracks: [] } // empty initially
```

render like below

```
{ this.state.tracks.length > 0 ? <Text style = {{color: "white"}}>{this.state.tracks[0].title}</Text> : null }
```

Comment: yeah but how can I acces it to it in another component?

Comment: Another component? state only works within the same component. Please explain in detail